# Returning 200 OK with doPost

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, shopify

I am trying to receive Shopify webhooks in Google App Script and can do so, but Shopify requires a response in 5 seconds. If it doesn't get a response "200 OK" it will fire again and again until Shopify deletes your webhook. Not good for me...

I got my webhook deleted with the below code:

```
function doPost(e) {
//Do stuff (code note included)
return ContentService.createTextOutput('200 OK');
}
```

I suppose there could be 2 problems

1. The code is wrong.
2. The code takes longer than 5 seconds to execute or fails

I wish Shopify would give more info on webhook history so I could see if it's not getting a response. Any insights of how I can solve this problem.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: If I had to guess it is because shopify cannot get access to your webapp? What is access like? What happens if you try to hit your webapp url from an unlogged in browser?

Comment: In addition to J.G comment, can you confirm the HTTP status code? Your WebApp deployment just returns plain text. The 5 seconds delay might be due to the security access. If there's an error can you please show it as an edit or comment?

Answer (score 0):

You state in your question that you do receive the webhook. The usual best practice is to verify the authenticity, and once that passes, you have the data (usually json). At that point, DO NOTHING but save the data for processing later, and return 200 OK as your response to the webhook.

DO NOT process the webhook, and then return 200 OK. The reason is quite simple. If your processing takes time, you kill your response back to Shopify in a timely manner.

A background job to process the data is ideal.

Comment: Thanks, I took your advice on storing it in Firebase and immediately responding. BUT now I can see the firebase is receiving the post about 3 times spaced 5 seconds apart. That inidicates that shopify is not happy with my response.

Comment: Is this really the right response???
return ContentService.createTextOutput('200 OK');

Comment: Only store a webhook for processing IF and ONLY IF you have not already stored it! Shopify does send multiple webhooks in a short period of time, so you have to guard against that yourself.

Comment: I got a safeguard process for multiple firings.

Comment: My problem is that multiple firings means shopify is not reciving my 200 OK

Comment: My point was, even if you DO return 200 OK, and you do it fast, you can get 2 or 3 versions of the same data sent to you. Obviously returning a 200 OK is the easy way out, but it won't stop dupes.

Comment: Ok sure but my webhook is still getting deleted!

Comment: Read up on how to make HTTP responses for your scripting language. Once you figure that out, return 200 OK status.